# Axis2 Web Services Client in IBM Websphere throws "Error in key derivation" exception

Tags: client, websphere, apache-axis, rampart

We have a secure web service client(rampart) deployed in IBM websphere. We are facing a scenario where the service provider (external) may go down frequently. Our client works fine and can access the service till it goes down. Once the provider comes back after a downtime, the client throws an exception :

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: General security error; nested exception is:
    org.apache.ws.security.conversation.ConversationException: Error in key derivation
```

To recover from this currently we need a server restart, which is unacceptable. Has anybody had a similar issue? Any pointer would be a great help.
Thanks in advance,
Ros